# how can i get two permissions sequentially?

Tags: android, facebook, permissions

i'm developing android app with facebook SDK 3.0 new.
I know the facebook's policy that i can not request two permissions at the same time and also can not request write permissions(publish_stream, publish_acition..etc) at the login button.

So, my question is, how can i request 'publish_stream' permissions automatically after user clicked logging button?

in my source code below,

```
private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {

    if (state.isOpened()) {

        if (pendingPublishReauthorization &&   state.equals(SessionState.OPENED_TOKEN_UPDATED)) {
            pendingPublishReauthorization = false;
            publishFeed(userName);
        }

        m_pd.show();
        Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                if (user != null) {

                    String username=buildUserInfoDisplay(user);
                    userName=username;
                    saveAccount(username, "facebook");

                    Log.d(com.dress.folio.Constants.FACEBOOK_TAG, "login success");
                    publishFeed(userName);
                    m_pd.dismiss();

                    //Activity GetActivity=getActivity();
                    //if(GetActivity != null) GetActivity.finish();


                }
            }
        });

    } else if (state.isClosed()) {
        Log.i(com.dress.folio.Constants.FACEBOOK_TAG, "Logged out..." + exception);
    }
}
```

when user clicked login button, onSessionStateChange() is called. so i tried to request 'publish_stream' with 'publishFeed()' after Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback().

```
Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                if (user != null) {

                    String username=buildUserInfoDisplay(user);
                    userName=username;
                    saveAccount(username, "facebook");

                    Log.d(com.dress.folio.Constants.FACEBOOK_TAG, "login success");
                    publishFeed(userName);
                    m_pd.dismiss();

                    //Activity GetActivity=getActivity();
                    //if(GetActivity != null) GetActivity.finish();

                }
            }
        });
```

publishFeed() is like :

```
private void publishFeed(String username) {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    SessionState state= session.getState();

    if (session != null){
        Log.d(com.dress.folio.Constants.FACEBOOK_TAG, "in publishstory(): "+ state);
        // Check for publish permissions    
        List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
        if (!isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions) ) {

            pendingPublishReauthorization = true;
            if(state == SessionState.OPENED_TOKEN_UPDATED) {
                Log.d(com.dress.folio.Constants.FACEBOOK_TAG, "in publishstory() if : OPENED_TOKEN_UPDATED" );
                Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSIONS);
                session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
            }

            return;
        }

        Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
        postParams.putString("name", username + " is logged in");
        // postParams.putString("caption", "Build great social apps and get more installs.");
        postParams.putString("description", "get the dress!!");
        postParams.putString("link", "https://www.facebook.com/pages/Dressfolio/183665935091337"); //dressfolio facebook page address
        postParams.putString("picture", "https://MY_APPLICATION.com/asset/facebook/app1/thumb2.png"); //thumbnail


        Request.Callback callback= new Request.Callback() {
            public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                Log.d(com.dress.folio.Constants.FACEBOOK_TAG, "callback()" );

                FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
                if (error != null) {
                    Log.d(com.dress.folio.Constants.FACEBOOK_TAG,"news feed error!" + error.toString());    
                } 
                else {
                    Log.d(com.dress.folio.Constants.FACEBOOK_TAG, "News Feed Posting success()" );
                }
            }
        };

        Request request = new Request(session, "me/feed", postParams, 
                HttpMethod.POST, callback);

        RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
        task.execute(); 


    }


}
```

but this always doesn't work because Sessionstate doesn't in 'OPENED_TOKEN_UPDATED' state.
How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can request more than one permission at a time, you just can't mix READ and PUBLISH permissions in the same request.

For your specific problem, it's because you're checking for SessionState.OPENED_TOKEN_UPDATED, whereas when a session first opens, it's in the SessionState.OPENED state. It's only when you request additional permissions that it transitions to the OPENED_TOKEN_UPDATED state.

Comment: basically, what i have noticed is that only "opened" and "opened_token_updated" states gets called. "opened" is called when you are authorizing for the first time, while, doing authorization the second time or 'ReAuthorizing with different list of permission', "opened_token_updated" is called.

And yes, DO NOT MIX read and write permissions. They are SEPARATE